# Query with validation settings on columns

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

We have two columns,Status(choice) and Date(Date and Time). Now I want to make the Date column mandatory when the `Status = Approved`.

I'm currently using this calculated values

```
=IF(AND([Status]="Approved",ISBLANK([Date])),"Not OK","OK")
```

The validation is working fine, but when I fill the Date column, it still says the Date column is not filled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Go to list setting --> Under general setting go to Validation setting and use below formula. This will make date field mandatory if status is `Approved`

```
=IF([Status]="Approved",IF([Date]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

Formula says if Status is Approved and Date is empty validation is false else true.
Hope this helps !